# AngularJs capture "tab" key press

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I work on angularJs v1 with [ngWig](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngWig) plugin.

I make a lot of questionary, each one having multiples  in the same page.

I want to press "tab" key to jump from the content of a  to the next one. Actually i have to click with the mouse inside the textarea because pressing tab key jump through each button of the component ( i have 9 on my app ) . Taking the following example, to write "question 1", "question 2","question 3" and so on.

[image]

https://plnkr.co/edit/dInpEicp5I5p5D1Cnf5w?p=preview

```
<body>
  <ng-wig ng-model="text1" class="ngwig-sm"></ng-wig>
  <ng-wig ng-model="text2" class="ngwig-sm"></ng-wig>
  <ng-wig ng-model="text3" class="ngwig-sm"></ng-wig>
  <ng-wig ng-model="text4" class="ngwig-sm"></ng-wig>
  <ng-wig ng-model="text5" class="ngwig-sm"></ng-wig>
</body>
```

Any idea how to jump from textarea to textarea ?

Comment: "never to textarea" It actually jumps to text areas in the plunkr you provided

Comment: yes, i updated the pluker with latest plugin code. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend removing tab focus from buttons as they are intended to be focusable. But if you are sure about removing tab focus from buttons, here's an approach you can take.

Assumption: You've Jquery as a dependency.

```
var ngWigButtons = $('ng-wig .nw-button');   // query buttons inside ngWig
for (var i=0, len=ngWigButtons.length; i<len; i++) {
    ngWigButtons.eq(i).attr('tabindex', -1); // remove tab focus
}
```